# Insert Query from Cloned Form Field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-clone

I have a project in which I have to be able make a multiple input if needed. I'm really new to JavaScript and the insert method that I'm familiar with is only POST method which I parsed it from Form. My question is how do I do to use query in my script?

This is my code and the query is needed between `Do...While` at the bottom:

```
<div id="form" class="hidden">
Nama : <input type="text" name="nama"><br/>
Kuantitas : <input type="text" name="kuantitas"><br/>
Kategori : <select name="idKategori">
    <?php
    while ($rowKategori = mysqli_fetch_object($resultKategori)) {
        echo "<option value='".$rowKategori->id."'>".$rowKategori->nama."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="bahan">
<input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove">
</div>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Tambah barang lain" id="add">
<input type="button" id="insert" value="Insert" style="margin-left: 50%;">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var form_index = 0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
        form_index++;
        $(this).parent().before($("#form").clone().attr("id", "form" + form_index));
        $("#form" + form_index).css("display", "inline");
        $("#form" + form_index + " :input").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + form_index);
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + form_index);
        });
        $("#remove" + form_index).click(function() {
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    });
    $("#insert").click(function() {
        var i = 0;
        do {
            i++;
        } while (i != 5);
    });
```

im really bad at english , so let me explain it as simple as i can.

1. i wanted to make a form field with submit button, like the usual.
   the difference is i wanted to make a clone button so i could add
   more form field with single submit button.
2. the code that i write is something that i learn from another page and im not familiar with it.
3. i dont know how to get vallue from the cloned page, and i dont know how to handle the value itself in the script as i really noob at javascript
4. what i wanted to do is how do you get value from all cloned form field while i click the submit button? the method i familiran with is POST method, but i thinking about writedown all my query on the javascript since the POST method could not do the looping for all the formfield, thats why i make the loop on the javascript

and im sorry with my english, im not really good at it

Comment: Might want to start by putting the javascirt in a script tag.  `<script type="text/javascript" > ... </script>` .  Also your `<form>` tag is unclosed.

Comment: woah i just reliaze it, its supposed to have that, i dont know why the form part is there, the second window supposed to be filled only with javascript. any how, do you know what line should i write between Do While in the tag #insert?

Comment: Um, I don't know what you are trying to do there.

Comment: me too lol , so let me explain it as simple as i can.
1. i wanted to make a form field with submit button, like the usual. the difference is i wanted to make a clone button so i could add more form field with single submit button.
2. the code that i write is something that i learn from another page

Comment: oh darn too long, i already fixed my question . i hope you understand and i hope all of you could make me understand of what im doing lol

Comment: ok, but it's still not clear the difference between the `Update` and `Insert` opperations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go, here is a fiddle of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ngjqxge/3/

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="form_block_wrapper" class="hidden"> <!-- added an outside wrapper -->
  <div class="form_block" class="hidden">
    Nama : <input type="text" name="nama[]"><br/>
    Kuantitas : <input type="text" name="kuantitas[]"><br/>
    Kategori : <select name="idKategori[]">
      <?php while ($rowKategori = mysqli_fetch_object($resultKategori)): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $rowKategori->id; ?>">
              <?php echo $rowKategori->nama; ?>
          </option>
       <?php endWhile; ?>
    </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" value="bahan">
  <input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove">
  </div>
</div> <!-- close #form_block_wrapper -->

<input type="button" value="Tambah barang lain" id="add">
<input type="button" id="insert" value="Insert" style="margin-left: 50%;">
```

Please note, I changed a number of things. Most importantly all the names of the inputs that would get submitted i added `[]`, so `nama` becomes `nama[]` etc.  Now if you were to submit this as a form, on the server side you would get arrays instead of single elements.  Single elements would get overwritten by the next dynamically created "form_block" so this is what we would need to process them.  The data you would expect on submission of the form would be like this ( assuming we had 3 "form_blocks" ):

```
   $_POST['nama'] = [
       0 => 'nama from first form block',
       1 => 'nama from second form block',
       2 => 'nama from third form block',
  ];

   $_POST['kuantitas'] = [
       0 => 'kuantitas from first form block',
       1 => 'kuantitas from second form block',
       2 => 'kuantitas from third form block',
  ];
  //etc...
```

Next, I removed any ID's as we know ids in HTML elements must be unique, so there is no point messing with them when we are creating and destroying dynamic content.  We could append an index as you originally did, but the selectors are simple enough so we don't really need to do this.  And it's worth it to keep things simple, why over complicate it.

I also used the "alternative" PHP syntax for the while block. `while(..):` with a colon instead of `while(..){` with a bracket.  It just looks better to me when mixed with HTML to have the `<?php endWhile; ?>` insteadd of `<?php } ?>`. It doesn't matter much here as this is small. But after adding buches of PHP, you would have all these hanging `}` brackets everywhere. It's easier to keep track of the close of code blocks when they are like `endIf;` `endWhile;` etc.  I also kept the HTML as HTML and not a big string that has to be echoed out, again because it looks better to me that way.  It also makes dealing with the quotes `"` easier then having to concatenate PHP `'<tag attr="'.$php.'">'`.

These things you can do either way, just I'm a bit particular and a perfectionist when it comes to formatting and readability. Sort of set in my ways.

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {

      //get and cache Outer HTML for .form_block
      var selectHtml = $('.form_block:eq(0)')[0].outerHTML;

      $("#add").click(function() {
            $('#form_block_wrapper').append(selectHtml);
      });

            //use .on for events on dynamic content ( event delegation )
     $("#form_block_wrapper").on('click', 'input[name="remove"]', function() {
         $(this).closest(".form_block").remove();
     });

      $("#insert").click(function() {
         //I have no idea what you want to do here?
         //Are you trying to insert something into the page
         //or Are you trying to insert the data into the DB, ie submit it to the server. 

          //you can serialze all the data https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
         //$('#form_block_wrapper').serialize(); 

         //you can get the selected options and get their value
         var d = [];
         $('select[name="idKategori[]"]').each( function(){
            d.push($(this).val());
         });
         alert(d.join(','));
      });

  });  //document.ready
})(jQuery); //assign jQuery to $ - for compatibility reasons.
```

The first thing to do here is not clone the `select` but instead take a snapshot of it's html.  Stored in `selectHtml`.  There is several reasons why this is better.

- if user changes the value of these fields, when we clone we have to reset all those values.
- if we remove all form blocks, there is nothing to clone and we are struck on a page without our form elements, tell we refresh.
- based just on the length of my code -vs- your orignal code, it should be obvious which method is simpler to handle.  Simple is easy to read and maintain, do more with less.

Another thing to note, is you were attaching the remove button's event to each button as they are created.  While this is ok, we can do better by using event delegation `$.on` to handle this element.

I still have no Idea what you want done with Insert,

- do you mean insert something into the page
- do you mean submit the form and insert the data somewhere.

but hopefully this helps

Comment: man , if only you know that this answer really help me out! thank you very much man, i really appreciate your help. again thank you ^^

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.